# R language italicize iteratively gera

Tags: r, plot, title, italics

Sorry for the very stupid question, I have been googleing for a while without finding a solution. I need to create several plots iteratively, whose titles are (1) picked from a previously created vector and (2) must be italicized.
I have tried several options with no adequate results, stuff like this:

```
# Main titles
m <- paste(LETTERS[1:10], LETTERS[11:20])
# Plots
for(i in 1:10){
     x <- runif(10, 1, 20)
     y <- runif(10, 1, 20)
     X11()
     plot(x,y, main = expression(italic(m[i])))
}
```

But what I got are plots with an "m" with an "i" as a subscript, not the corresponding content in the vector. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to achieve what you want

```
# Main titles
m <- paste(LETTERS[1:10], LETTERS[11:20])
# Plots
for(i in 1:10){
  x <- runif(10, 1, 20)
  y <- runif(10, 1, 20)
  X11()
  plot(x,y, main = substitute(paste(italic(x)), list(x = m[i])))
}
```

One of the plots
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `bquote`. The expression in `.()` will be evaluated:

```
plot(x,y, main = bquote(italic(.(m[i]))) )
```

[image]